# Why can't I simulate a current sensing IC (LT6100) using Proteus 8?

Tags: integrated-circuit, current-measurement, proteus

According to this image, I should be able to design a high side current sensing circuit with a gain of 10V/V using an [LT6100](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/6100fd.pdf):

[image]

However, if I try to simulate this using Proteus 8 I get an error.
Here is the circuit I'm simulating: [image]

And here is the error:[image]

Any idea why this is happening?

Thank you!

Comment: You are completely right! That is why the error appeared. I was not careful at the datasheet. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Data sheet Vcc has to be a minimum of 2.7V (to 36V)

Also Vs+ has to be Vcc + 1.4V or 4.1V (@ Vcc of 2.7) to 48V

HTH

Comment: Thank you! I didn't read the **must** be Vcc + 1.4V. I thought that's the maximum range.